KQL query returning data omitting last 7 days

union 
workspace(""workspace1"").InsightsMetrics,
workspace(""workspace2"").InsightsMetrics,
workspace(""workspace3"").InsightsMetrics,
workspace(""workspace4"").InsightsMetrics,
workspace(""workspace5"").InsightsMetrics,
workspace(""workspace6"").InsightsMetrics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d)
| where Origin == "vm.azm.ms" and Namespace == "Memory"
| extend TotalMemoryGB=(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/memorySizeMB"])/(1024)
| summarize AvailableMemoryGB = round(avg(Val)/(1024),2) by Computer, TotalMemoryGB, _ResourceId
| extend Availabile_Memory_Percentage= round((AvailableMemoryGB/TotalMemoryGB)*100, 2)
| project Computer, TotalMemoryGB, AvailableMemoryGB,Availabile_Memory_Percentage

The query omits data from the last 7 days (not sure why). The table has retention of 30 days.I am pulling the data from the InsightsMetrics table. How do i troubleshoot? And can i make the query more efficient? Appreciate feedback


KQL query returning data omitting last 7 days:

Below are the few points to check and resolve the issue:
Firstly, take the sample amount of data and check the data is generated properly during the omitted period. To do that, use below query as detailed.
InsightsMetrics
| union workspace("workspace-ahnaviCMg6").InsightsMetrics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| summarize count() by Origin


I could see that there is no data for me in the given time period (for last 7 days). Now try executing the complete query to retrieve the expected output.
Alternatively, you can also use make-series Kusto functional operator which works as similar as summarize operator.
The only difference is:

It can use many of the same aggregation functions that summarize can.

| union workspace("workspace-ahnaviCMg6").InsightsMetrics
| make-series count() on TimeGenerated > ago(7d)

If still the issue persists, try retrieving the logs separately (resource wise) and join all the tables once retrieved.
